# more than one value with comma in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

`colum 1, colum2
a,b,c     30
b,c,f     40
a,g,z     50
.
.
.`

Using above dataframe with col1,2 I'd like to have dataframe as below dataframe with col3, 4. 
Additionally, col1 consists of values with commas. col4 consists of sum of col2 following col3.

`column3, column4
a        80
b        70
c        70
f        40
g        50
z        50`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
df = (df.set_index('colum2')['colum1']
        .str.split(',', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='column3')
        .groupby('column3', as_index=False)['colum2']
        .sum()
        .rename(columns={'colum2':'column4'})
      )
print (df)
  column3  column4
0       a       80
1       b       70
2       c       70
3       f       40
4       g       50
5       z       50
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `colum2`
2. Create `DataFrame` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
3. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
4. Create index by columns by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
5. [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum`
6. Last rename column if necessary

Another solution:

```
from itertools import chain

a = df['colum1'].str.split(',')
lens = a.str.len()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column3' : list(chain.from_iterable(a)), 
    'column4' : df['colum2'].repeat(lens)
}).groupby('column3', as_index=False)['column4'].sum()

print (df)
  column3  column4
0       a       80
1       b       70
2       c       70
3       f       40
4       g       50
5       z       50
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create lists by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
2. Get lengths of lsits by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html)
3. Last [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) columns and flatten `colum1`
4. [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My dataframe has over 5millon rows. Could you tell me which way would be more efficient?

Comment: Done. Thank you so much! :)